# about Poincare map

Tags: dynamical-systems, periodic-functions

I saw that the Poincaré map is defined by the flow of the periodic system with the least period $T$. that is, $$P(x):=\phi_T(x)$$
is a Poincaré map with flow $\phi$ of time $T$.

but I think if we define it like this way, it is just $P(x)=x$ because the solution is periodic, $$P(x)=\phi_T(x)=\phi_0(x)=x.$$
did I see the right definition of Poincaré map? if I did, what do I understand wrong?

Edit: I read the wikipedia, but still don't get it. could you explain it more simply, like, using flow or something? with some examples if you don't mind?

Comment: I would suggest reading section 8.5 of "Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos" by Steven Strogatz. It gives a very nice and simple explanation to everything you are asking

Comment: A "periodic system"  means that the **flow** is periodic, not that the **solutions** are periodic.